# using mysql explain plans to determine if indexes are correct

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to update a table from contents in another table.  TBL1 is getting an Update from related records from TB2, and my problem is that while I created a monster of a machine, the code is still going slowly.  I'm hoping that there's a programmic solution to speed this one up.  Thank you.  MySQL isn't my strong suit.  Trying to get better.  Appreciate any wisdom.

I have this query:

```
UPDATE DB.TBL1 tgt
inner join DB.TB2 src on tgt.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID = src.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID
SET
tgt.Agent_SK=src.Agent_SK, tgt.Property_Address=src.Property_Address, tgt.Property_City=src.Property_City, tgt.Property_State=src.Property_State, tgt.Property_Zip=src.Property_Zip, tgt.Property_Zip_4=src.Property_Zip_4, tgt.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number=src.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, tgt.County_FIPS=src.County_FIPS, tgt.Internal_FA_Property_Ref_ID=src.Internal_FA_Property_Ref_ID, tgt.Property_Type=src.Property_Type, tgt.Property_SubType=src.Property_SubType, tgt.Lot_Size_Sq_Ft=src.Lot_Size_Sq_Ft, tgt.Home_Size=src.Home_Size, tgt.Home_or_Building_Style=src.Home_or_Building_Style, tgt.Heating_Type=src.Heating_Type, tgt.Heating_Fuel_Type=src.Heating_Fuel_Type, tgt.Cooling_Type=src.Cooling_Type, tgt.Cooling_Fuel_Type=src.Cooling_Fuel_Type, tgt.Number_of_Stories=src.Number_of_Stories, tgt.Year_Built=src.Year_Built, tgt.Roof_Type=src.Roof_Type, tgt.Exterior_Construction=src.Exterior_Construction, tgt.Number_of_Bedrooms=src.Number_of_Bedrooms, tgt.Number_of_Bathrooms=src.Number_of_Bathrooms, tgt.Number_of_Garages=src.Number_of_Garages, tgt.Garage_Type=src.Garage_Type, tgt.Pool_Features=src.Pool_Features, tgt.View_Features=src.View_Features, tgt.Price_per_Square_Feet=src.Price_per_Square_Feet, tgt.Porch=src.Porch, tgt.Patio=src.Patio, tgt.Deck=src.Deck, tgt.Basement=src.Basement, tgt.Air_Conditioner=src.Air_Conditioner, tgt.Number_of_Fireplaces=src.Number_of_Fireplaces, tgt.Presence_of_Fireplace=src.Presence_of_Fireplace, tgt.Fireplace_Description=src.Fireplace_Description, tgt.Interior_Features=src.Interior_Features, tgt.Exterior_Features=src.Exterior_Features, tgt.Existing_Structures=src.Existing_Structures, tgt.Lot_Features=src.Lot_Features, tgt.Zoning=src.Zoning, tgt.Neighborhood=src.Neighborhood, tgt.School_District=src.School_District, tgt.Elementary_School=src.Elementary_School, tgt.Middle_School=src.Middle_School, tgt.High_School=src.High_School, tgt.Appliances=src.Appliances, tgt.Approximate_Lot_Dimensions=src.Approximate_Lot_Dimensions, tgt.Topogrophy=src.Topogrophy, tgt.Waterfront_Features=src.Waterfront_Features, tgt.Water=src.Water, tgt.Water_Source=src.Water_Source, tgt.Water_Amenities=src.Water_Amenities, tgt.Water_Access=src.Water_Access, tgt.Water_Heater=src.Water_Heater, tgt.FA_Calculated_Days_on_Market=src.FA_Calculated_Days_on_Market, tgt.Current_Original_Listing_Date=src.Current_Original_Listing_Date, tgt.Listing_Number=src.Listing_Number, tgt.Status=src.Status, tgt.Status_Sub_Type=src.Status_Sub_Type, tgt.Rental_Indicator=src.Rental_Indicator, tgt.Current_Listing_Price=src.Current_Listing_Price, tgt.Sold_Price=src.Sold_Price, tgt.Sold_Date=src.Sold_Date, tgt.FA_Adjusted_Sold_Price=src.FA_Adjusted_Sold_Price, tgt.FA_Sold_Price_Range=src.FA_Sold_Price_Range, tgt.Listing_Agent_License_Number=src.Listing_Agent_License_Number, tgt.Listing_Agent_Name=src.Listing_Agent_Name, tgt.Listing_Agent_Address=src.Listing_Agent_Address, tgt.Listing_Agent_Phone=src.Listing_Agent_Phone, tgt.Listing_Agent_Email=src.Listing_Agent_Email, tgt.Office_Name=src.Office_Name, tgt.Office_Address=src.Office_Address, tgt.Office_Phone=src.Office_Phone, tgt.Office_Email=src.Office_Email, tgt.Listing_Tracking_ID=src.Listing_Tracking_ID, tgt.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID=src.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID, tgt.Update_Timestamp=src.Update_Timestamp, tgt.Add_Change_Delete_Indicator=src.Add_Change_Delete_Indicator, tgt.Property_Details=src.Property_Details, tgt.Current_Listing_Ind=src.Current_Listing_Ind, tgt.Current_Rental_Ind=src.Current_Rental_Ind, tgt.LoadDate=src.LoadDate

where tgt.LoadDate>src.LoadDate;
```

The explain plan produced:

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type|possible_keys                              |key|key_len|ref|rows     |filtered|Extra      |
--+-----------+-----+----------+----+-------------------------------------------+---+-------+---+---------+--------+-----------+
 1|SIMPLE     |src  |          |ALL |                                           |   |       |   |  1378013|   100.0|           |
 1|UPDATE     |tgt  |          |ALL |MLS_FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID_IDX|   |       |   |180531097|   33.33|Using where|
```

my problem is that this is still taking too long, even with indexes on the table's DDL:

-- offrs.MLS definition

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL1` (
  `Agent_SK` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_Address` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_City` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_State` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_Zip` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_Zip_4` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number` varchar(156) DEFAULT NULL,
  `County_FIPS` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Internal_FA_Property_Ref_ID` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_Type` varchar(340) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_SubType` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lot_Size_Sq_Ft` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Home_Size` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Home_or_Building_Style` text,
  `Heating_Type` varchar(788) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Heating_Fuel_Type` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cooling_Type` varchar(594) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cooling_Fuel_Type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number_of_Stories` varchar(468) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year_Built` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Roof_Type` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Exterior_Construction` varchar(514) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number_of_Bedrooms` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number_of_Bathrooms` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number_of_Garages` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Garage_Type` text,
  `Pool_Features` varchar(586) DEFAULT NULL,
  `View_Features` varchar(486) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price_per_Square_Feet` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Porch` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Patio` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Deck` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Basement` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Air_Conditioner` varchar(74) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number_of_Fireplaces` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Presence_of_Fireplace` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fireplace_Description` varchar(562) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interior_Features` text,
  `Exterior_Features` text,
  `Existing_Structures` varchar(324) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lot_Features` varchar(908) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zoning` varchar(514) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Neighborhood` varchar(314) DEFAULT NULL,
  `School_District` varchar(514) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Elementary_School` varchar(514) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Middle_School` varchar(514) DEFAULT NULL,
  `High_School` varchar(518) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Appliances` varchar(1750) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Approximate_Lot_Dimensions` varchar(404) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Topogrophy` varchar(118) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Waterfront_Features` varchar(514) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Water` varchar(522) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Water_Source` varchar(230) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Water_Amenities` varchar(48) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Water_Access` varchar(104) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Water_Heater` varchar(84) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FA_Calculated_Days_on_Market` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Current_Original_Listing_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Number` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status_Sub_Type` varchar(58) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rental_Indicator` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Current_Listing_Price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sold_Price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sold_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FA_Adjusted_Sold_Price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FA_Sold_Price_Range` varchar(42) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Agent_License_Number` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Agent_Name` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Agent_Address` varchar(324) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Agent_Phone` varchar(46) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Agent_Email` varchar(104) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Office_Name` varchar(404) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Office_Address` varchar(324) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Office_Phone` varchar(44) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Office_Email` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listing_Tracking_ID` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Update_Timestamp` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Add_Change_Delete_Indicator` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Property_Details` text,
  `Current_Listing_Ind` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Current_Rental_Ind` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LoadDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IDX_MLS_LTID` (`Listing_Tracking_ID`),
  KEY `MLS_FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID_IDX` (`FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHA
```

The PRocessTree does not show any inhibitors:

```
show processlist;
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id      | User            | Host                | db   | Command | Time    | State                  | Info                                                                                                 |
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       5 | event_scheduler | localhost           | NULL | Daemon  | 5816018 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 1017661 | root            | <<IP>>:57056     | NULL | Sleep   |      26 |                        | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 1292175 | root            | <<IP>>:52670    | NULL | Query   |  346368 | executing              | UPDATE DB.TBL1 tgt
inner join DB.TB2 src on tgt.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID = s |
| 1371178 | root            | <<IP>>:52498     | NULL | Sleep   |       0 |                        | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 1371288 | root            | <<IP>>:57938     | NULL | Sleep   |      26 |                        | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 1371302 | root            | <<IP>>:37392     | NULL | Sleep   |      11 |                        | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 1371331 | root            | <<IP>>:48040 | NULL | Query   |       0 | init                   | show processlist                                                                                     |
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: yes, the names were changed to protect the innocent.

Any wisdom would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: You didn't include the DDL for `TB2` but it looks like the JOIN isn't using any index, so both tables are incurring a table-scan. Thus it will be forced to do row comparisons without aid of indexes: 1378013 * 180531097, or about 250 trillion! No wonder it isn't completing in a satisfactory time.

Comment: This query needs in the index by `(FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID, LoadDate)` in both tables.

Comment: Only one table needs an index for this single join - Considering that the WHERE condition is actually a JOIN condition. IMHO the given index should be used. Try [FORCE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) and see if that improves the performance.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Index forcing is not recommended and must be used with a caution - the index usage may become harmful when the data statistic changes, and it may not improve but decrease the performance.

Comment: @Akina I'm suggesting it to see if there is any differnce in performance. If not - then maybe not using the index was the right decision of MySQL and the query is just slow due to data distribution and the huge number of rows being updated. Note that OP didn't even define "slow".

Comment: No I did not do an index on tb2 because it’s a truncate and reload.  But I’m hearing that I should set index anyways. I’ll try it and see what happens.  More to follow.

Comment: @arcee123      24 hours from now, please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tb1; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE tb2; C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "tb1"; D) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "tb2"; and NEW E) EXPLAIN (your query);  so we can analyze your current index availability.  When the column after 'possible keys' has no value, you can be sure NO INDEX was used for the selection.  There has to be a reason.  Do NOT post what you think created the table.  There is NOTHING better than SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for getting to current truth on table design.

Comment: copy.  i can do that tonight. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The indicator you need to take a look at in the result of explain plans is the “TYPE” column. It determines if the queries go through the index or not. The value “ALL” means the query accessing the tables sequentially / full scan table. The possible_keys show the probability of the index would be used and the key is the index of queries accessing the data.

Another thing, you can see how many rows are filtered through the index by looking at the filtered column, it’s a percentage of the data read through an index.

After you have knowledge of the fundamental of how to read the explain plan, you can check the queries & table structure to see if the queries accessing the right index as you expect.